# Use of the verb "extract" with the adverb "as"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adverbs

Can I use the verb "extract" with the adverb "as"?

My example would be the following sentence:

> A reference type is extracted as an EClassifier.

Is this sentence correct? The context is that I describe a model extraction process where every reference type leads to an EClassifier in the extracted model (technical paper).

Comment: Google NGram says it's possible:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extracted%20as&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cextracted%20as%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The grammar looks perfectly fine

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was a little bit confused because Grammarly told me that I should use "extract from". But I am glad this is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are discussing a transformation, "as", is correct.
If you were discussing the removal of a constituent from a conglomerate, you would use, "from".